# Do you need to open client firewall for WS-AT to work with WCF?

Tags: wcf, transactions, wshttpbinding, wsat

I am getting the following error trying to communicate from WCF -> WCF across the internet with a SSL certificate. I have 'No authentication required' checked in the WS-AT configuration on the server.

After a few seconds I'm getting the following message on my client, and trying to figure out what is wrong in my configuration (or understanding of WS-AT).

> The flowed transaction could not be
>   unmarshaled. The following exception
>   occurred: The WS-AtomicTransaction
>   protocol service could not unmarshal
>   the flowed transaction. The following
>   exception occured: A fault reply with
>   code CoordinatorRegistrationFailed was
>   received. The fault reason follows:
>   The WS-AT protocol service failed to
>   register with its coordinator. A
>   connection could not be established.

Looking at the log file on the server I find a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702582(VS.90).aspx and the following trace message

> Microsoft.Transactions.TransactionBridge.RegistrationCoordinatorFailed
>   **Traced if the local TransactionManager is not able to
>   Register with its superior
>   TransactionManager due to the
>   inability to send a message.**

So I'm wondering... is the server attempting to communicate with the client through a different channel to the SSL connection originally established by the client. I'm pretty sure thats what it's trying to do for me to end up with this message. The client is my laptop (currently in Starbucks) so there's no chance of any incoming connections.

So is it possible to use WS-AT transactions where only the server has an open firewall? Assuming it is possible - what do i have to do to allow for it? I'm finding very little information about necessary configuration - even in my massive Programming WCF book .

---

Bonus: Here's a few small tips for anyone trying to get WS-AT working :

- If when trying to [install the WS-AT tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733943.aspx) you can't get it to appear - and you're running an x64 operating system - make sure you're using the [x64 version of RegAsm.exe](http://blogical.se/blogs/mikael_sand/archive/2009/08/28/configuring-ws-atomic-transaction-support-in-windows-7-64-bit.aspx):
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe /codebase wsatui.dll
- If once installing WS-AT, configuring it for incoming connections and restarting MCAT you still get errors about the protocol being disabled you may have forgotton to restart IIS(!)

Comment: What on earth is MCAT?

Comment: Weird. I think that was meant to be MDTC - Microsoft distributed transaction coordinator service

Comment: now, MSDTC, I know. thanks.